# The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, file-management

I have a razor view page where I need to check whether or not a file exists before attempting to display it to the user, otherwise display a default image placeholder.
Below is the code I wrote

```
@{
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@parent.Photo) && File.Exists(Server.MapPath($"~/images/parents/thumbs/@parent.Photo")))
    {
      <img src="~/images/parents/thumbs/@parent.Photo" class="rounded- 
       circle img-fluid" />
     }
     else
     {
      @: No photo
     }
 }
```

but I get the error that says as follows

> The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context

So I cannot build the application. 
I have tried to add the following using statements on the view page

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

but it made no difference

My application is running on ASP.NET-Core 3.1 on windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `Server.MapPath` does not exit in ASP.NET.Core and instead you should use `IWebHostEnvironment` interface. inject `IWebHostEnvironment` into your view and use it.

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env

@{
 var path = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, $"images/parents/thumbs/@parent.Photo"));
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@parent.Photo) && File.Exists(path))
    {
      <img src="~/images/parents/thumbs/@parent.Photo" class="rounded- 
       circle img-fluid" />
     }
     else
     {
      @: No photo
     }
 }
```

for more information read this article
[Server.MapPath Equivalent in ASP.NET Core](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: @inject IWebHostEnvironment env gives the following error message "The type or namespace IWebHostEnvironment could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET core 3.x full namespace is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment ` and if you are using ASP.NET Core 2.x namespace is `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment`.

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Combine' and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). That is the new error message after doing the above recommendation

Comment: `var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(env...`